# How to save url inside android string.xml file and then use it in java class

Tags: java, android, xml

I am have an android example application in which url(s) are written inside the java class as static data. I got to know that this is not the best practice in android to save url. So my question is, how can I save these url(s) in android string.xml file and use them in my java class. I have put the example code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class UserFunctions {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private JSONParser jsonParser;

// Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
// use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

}

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: I think having the URLs in your code is prefereable.  You use string resources when the data will change based on locale.  URLs are universal-  unless you're linking to specific URLs based on language, which isn't the case here.  This makes them poor matches for string resources.